# Count number of hashtags inside multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've multiple `<p>` on my page. They do not have classes or ids. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to target every single of these `<p>`s count how many hashtags are in there and display the result inside the `<span>`.

structure example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>
        #test #test #test
    </p>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <p>
        #test #test #test
    </p>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <p>
        #test #test #test
    </p>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

this is working but it's counting everything:

```
$(function() {
    var text = $(this).find("pre").text();
    var hashTags = text.split("#").length;
        var result = hashTags - 1;

    $('#output').html('words count: ' + result);
});
```

Comment: I don't see how your code is working at all, given that `this` will refer to the `window` and you're looking for `pre` elements which don't exist in your HTML sample...?

Comment: Which element has the ID of `output`? There are three different `span`s in your HTML, none of which has that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```js
//loop through every element with class parent
$(".parent").each( function(index) {
  //get number of tags per in <p>
  var tags = $(this).find("p").text().split("#").length - 1;
  //write the number of tags in <span>
  $(this).find("span").text(tags);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <p>
        #test #test #test
    </p>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <p>
        #test #test #test
    </p>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <p>
        #test #test #test
    </p>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong selector, replace it with:

```
  var text = $(this).find("p").text();
```

Note also that in the code you posted there's no `output` div.
Check this [pen](http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/VjoQRG?editors=1011) for a working version.